# Full managing of fragments flow in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, transactions, fragment

I have a special flow of fragments in my app, so I need to be able to switch to any fragment, while keeping fragments in memory whenever possible (so if it's tight on memory, it's ok that the fragment will be released).

So far, I've succeeded doing a replace of the current fragment, but the thing is that the previous fragment is always being destroyed, so if I go back to it (using the action bar, for example), it's re-created and that takes some time.

The reason I use fragments instead of activities is the nice usage of the action bar, the ability to put multiple fragments inside the same container, the non-flexible activities-intents usage, etc...

The reason why I don't use the "Back" stack is that I wish to go to any fragment from any fragment, since the flow can change.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Fragment fragment=... ; //get the fragment from cache or create if not available yet...
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainActivity_fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```

I have also tried to use ViewPager, but since I don't want to have the sliding effect (which allows you to slide to other fragments) and since one of the fragments already include a viewPager, it's an obstacle. Disabling the sliding effect on the main viewPager somehow disables it on the other one.

BTW, I'm using the android support library for the fragments and not the native API.

**my question is:
how can i achieve full control of which fragment to go to , while maximizing speed and avoiding too much memory being used for fragments ?**

---

EDIT:
for now , i use the next workaround :
for the onDestroyView , i take the parent of the created view and remove the created view from there .

for the onCreateView , if i already have the created view from before , i return it .

however , i think it's a very risky thing to do , since i'm not sure of how fragments managing work , so it might cause weird problems . plus ,i'm not sure what will happen if android decides that it has low memory - will it destroy unused fragments (which is good) or will it cause out-of-memory exceptions (which is bad) .

Comment: where is your question? how can we help? Is it about the delay when a fragments gets created? Did you check the underlying data creation that is required for your fragment to appear?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your comment regarding "it's very risky". Since the consequences of your approach are not really clear, I would not recommend using this.

To better understand your issue and to give you some indications:

1. what do you consider to be slow? I keep switching fragments "like crazy" too, and it works OK on a tablet, however on some low-end phones it takes much longer - but is still acceptable
2. How much work do your fragments need to be created? ie what kind  of underlying data needs to be preapared each time? (again, I have several list fragments with more than 1k entries, they get prepared each time, and it's quite fast)
3. how do you exaclty replace fragments? In particular do you call `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: 1. speed is not the main issue . the main issue is flexibility - go to whatever fragment i need without re-creating it when possible.
2.well , some fragments need to have a webview inside them which should not be refreshed but only resumed , and some have ViewPager .
3.already written in the snippet .

Comment: question about memory does not really seem a fragemnt issue, since fragments do not require particularily intense memory - afaik it's even less than activities. It seems more a memory question in general? right? Then you need to be more specific what you want to do and why do you think it needs lots of memory. by the way to increase the chances that any memory will be kept "in direct access" you need to have references to them, the more references, the more often you request the higher the probability they will be kept in fast access storage

Comment: again , please read the question i've asked . the main issue is flexibility - how to go to any fragment from any fragment without re-creating it , and another question is if the solution will release fragments when the app takes too much memory ,so that i won't have the out-of-memory exception so easily.

Comment: did you do a memory analysis on how much memory it really needs. I am currently working on an app with quite heavy bitmaps in several fragments. All I have to do is to ensure that whatever memory I use is recycled quickly. For example the fragments require all around 10-20MB of data and all are recycled and recreated when jumping around. No problem whatsoever. If you are really concerened about it, store the underlying data and re-use this. Why not optimize once you run into problems and have done the profiling?

Comment: Just a though have you checked detach and attach methods for fragments already...

Comment: again and again : the main question i ask here is NOT the memory . the main issue is how to allow the flexibility , while minimizing re-creation of the fragments. if too much memory is used , i would expect that some fragments will be destroyed in order to reclaim memory.

Comment: currently  , what i have is something that replaces the current fragment , but it re-creates the fragment each time , so i've saved the view to be returned . as i've written, this workaround looks risky.

Comment: have you checked d detach and attach methods for fragments  - this might be what you want?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish your goal is to use FragmentTransaction.show and FragmentTransaction.hide.  You can use Fragment.isAdded to determine whether to show or to call FragmentTranscation.add the first time.  The downside is that you won't get Pause/Resume events when fragments are shown and hidden; you will need to override onHiddenChanged. You will also have to manage your own stack if you want to support back navigation.